# How can I create a middle tab button like these with React Navigation?

Tags: css, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-v6

I need to create a bottom tab navigation with React Navigation (v6) like this one:

[image]

So far what I did was:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function SettingsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Settings!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="ForYou" component={ForYouScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Maps" component={MapsScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Premium" component={PremiumScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Shop" component={ShopScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Media" component={MediaScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

But I'm not sure the right approach for styling, should I try to style 3rd tab button somehow? or should I create a 4 tabs navigation and create a floating button on the middle, but in this case how do I create room for it within the tabs on the middle?

Any idea or snippet is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is add a custom tabBarButton and use svg in it like this (you will need to install react-native-svg)

```
 //background svg which will create space
 const TabBg = ({ color = '#FFFFFF', ...props }) => {
  return (
    <Svg width={75} height={61} viewBox="0 0 75 61" {...props}>
      <Path
        d="M75.2 0v61H0V0c4.1 0 7.4 3.1 7.9 7.1C10 21.7 22.5 33 37.7 33c15.2 0 27.7-11.3 29.7-25.9.5-4 3.9-7.1 7.9-7.1h-.1z"
        fill={color}
      />
    </Svg>
  );
};

//custom tabBarButton
const TabBarAdvancedButton = ({ bgColor, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container} pointerEvents="box-none">
      <TabBg color={bgColor} style={styles.background} />
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={props.onPress}>
        // any image or icon here
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    position: 'relative',
    width: 75,
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  background: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
  },
  button: {
    top: -22.5,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 27,
    backgroundColor: '#E94F37',
  },
  buttonIcon: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: '#F6F7EB'
  }
});



// add your custom tabBarButton component
<Tab.Screen
 name="Premium"
  component={PremiumScreen}
  options={{
    tabBarButton: (props) => (
      <TabBarAdvancedButton
        bgColor={barColor} // background space color.
        {...props}
      />
    )
  }}
/>
```

You can customize this the way you want if you need more help you can follow the below mentioned article. This works with react-navigation v6.

[ReactNative: TabBar With Float Button](https://medium.com/litslink/reactnative-curved-tabbar-dc62e681c24d)

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Thanks for contributing an answer!  However, link-only answers are usually considered insufficient/incomplete, as they could become useless should the link change or become broken at some point in the future.  Could you update this post to include some more detail so that it will remain valuable should the link become compromised?  If not, this content is better suited as a comment than as an answer...

Comment: Thank you for informing this. I completely understand. However, I would need 50 reps to be able to comment that is why I posted it as an answer, should I delete this answer?

Comment: I think in its current form it probably will not be considered a complete answer and is likely to be closed.  As such, you _could_ delete it, _OR_ you could update the answer and bring some detail from the link into your answer, and perhaps the OP will upvote and mark it as complete to earn you some reputation :)  Your choice, of course.  Happy coding!